# Using Num.msg from Beginner tutorial

Tags: ros, messages, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please modify or guide me to where I can learn to modify the talker.cpp and listener.cpp given in the beginner_tutorials to send the message Num.msg defined in the same series of tutorials. This is to help understand how to use complex msgs later on.

I replaced the example code by the following lines wherever I felt was necessary but this is not getting compiled.

**talker.cpp**

```
#include "beginner_tutorials/Num.h"
ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<beginner_tutorials::Num>("chatter", 1000);
beginner_tutorials::Num num;
// std::stringstream ss;
// ss <<"hello world" << count;
num = 123456789;
ROS_INFO("%d",num);
chatter_pub.publish(num);
```

**listener.cpp**

```
#include "beginner_tutorials/Num.h"
void chatterCallback(const beginner_tutorials::ConstPtr &num)
{
    ROS_INFO("I heard: [%d]",  num->data);
}
```

Also please suggest a way to understand the Num.h, std_msgs/String.h file generated by ROS, if it is to be understood at the first place to use ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221229/using-num.msg-from-beginner-tutorial/) by [arttp2](https://answers.ros.org/users/24037/arttp2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2015-11-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-11-19**:
What is the error message?

**Comment by [arttp2](https://answers.ros.org/users/24037/arttp2/) on 2015-11-19**:
In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/talker.cpp:25:7: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘beginner_tutorials::Num’ and ‘int’)
num = 123456789;

one of the error messages, the first one.

**Comment by [arttp2](https://answers.ros.org/users/24037/arttp2/) on 2015-11-19**:
Thanks for editing my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The type of the message is `beginner_tutorials::Num`, not int. However, it probably has a member of type in, usually named data or something. You need to set that instead of the message directly.

Usually you refer to the message definition file for that and not the ROS message headers. These can be read and understood, but are not meant to be.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-11-19**:
In other words, the line `num = 123456789;` should probably be changed to something like `num.data = 123456789;`

**Comment by [arttp2](https://answers.ros.org/users/24037/arttp2/) on 2015-11-19**:
after adding num.data, it again says no member such as data (because .data may be defined for the String message) , so where can I find the members for the message, and a comprehensive usage details for the custom msg.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-11-19**:
As @dornhege said, you need to be looking at the "Num.msg" file to see the message definition. E.g. see how the [std_msgs/String](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/String.html) has a single field of type "string" named "data". You need to find the equivalent file for your message.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-11-19**:
If your workspace is setup correctly, you should be able to see the message definition at the command line using `rosmsg show`. E.g. `rosmsg show std_msgs/String`